# How do I loop through a MS Access database and lock all the tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use the following code to lock some data tables in my database:

```
Application.SetHiddenAttribute acTable, "Employees", True
```

And I use this code to loop through a form to clear all the text boxes in a userform:

```
Dim ctl_text As Control
For Each ctl_text In Me.Controls
    If ctl_text.ControlType = acTextBox Then ctl_text = Null
Next
Set ctl_text = Nothing
```

I was hoping to combine the above logic to be able to loop through the database and lock all the tables.

I was trying the following:

```
Dim tdf As Dao.TableDef
Dim db As Dao.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If (VBA.Left(tdf.Name, 6) = "prefix") Then
Set Application.SetHiddenAttribute = True
   End If
Next tdf
```

I am however getting an error telling me that the "SetHiddenAttribute" argument is not optional.

Any idea how I can go about this?

Comment: `Application.SetHiddenAttribute acTable, tdf.Name, True` would be the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have this in mind:

```vb
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If VBA.Left(tdf.Name, 6) = "prefix" Then
        tdf.Attributes = tdf.Attributes Or dbHiddenObject
    End If
Next
```

Please note, that this not "locks" the tables, only hide them from the normal views.

To remove the hidden attribute:

```vb
        tdf.Attributes = tdf.Attributes And Not dbHiddenObject
```

Comment: It should be `Or` instead of `And` to work (and to not clear other attributes).

Comment: Just checking  - when using the Attributes function do you not risk losing the table when compacting? Also, what would the reverse of the above be should I want to unhide it?

Comment: Added the code line to remove the attribute. Can't tell about the survival from a compact/repair - it should be easy to check out.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, I am going to run it on a copy of the database and give feedback.